# dynamically set value of DataKeyNames in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How i could set the value of DataKeyNames of gridview in C# code?

since my gridview is generated dynamically, i need to set it from .cs file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write code in cs file like

> GridView d;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    d = new GridView();

    d.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Column1", "Column2" };
    form1.Controls.Add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set it like any other property of the grid:

```
myGrid.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"Id", "Name"};
```

This corresponds to the following declarative code:

```
<asp:GridView id="myGrid" DataKeyNames="Id,Name" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
myGridView.DataKeyNames =new string[]{"PrimaryKeyId"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set DataKeyNames Property of your GridView.

```
{YourGriViewID}.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"ColV", "Col"};
```